# Extract last word in a string after comma if there are multiple words else the first word

Tags: r, string-matching, stringr, stringi

I have data where the words as follows

```
 location<- c("xyz, sss, New Zealand", "USA", "Pris,France")
 id<- c(1,2,3)
 df<-data.frame(location,id)
```

I would like to extract the country name from the data. The tricky part is if i extract just the last word then I will have only one record (France).

```
library(stringr)
df$country<- word(df$location,-1)
```

Any ideas on how to extract country data from this data?

```
 id  location                      country
  1   xyz, sss, New Zealand        New Zealand
  2   USA                          USA
  3   Pris,France                  France
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can try `sub`

```
 df$country <- sub('.*,\\s*', '', df$location)
 df$country
 #[1] "New Zealand" "USA"         "France"
```

Or

```
 library(stringr)
 str_extract(df$location, '\\b[^,]+$')
 #[1] "New Zealand" "USA"         "France"
```

Comment: `explanation [sub]:` from `df$location`, replace any character `.`, occuring any number of times `*`, upto a comma, followed by any number/type of whitespace `\\s` with nothing `''`
`explanation [str_extract]:` from `df$location`, provide 1 or multiple `+` whole words `\\b`, not `[ ]` in a string that ends in a comma `^,`  until the end of the string `$`. (so basically, provide all whole words after comma)

Answer (score 1):

`stringi` solution:

```
require(stringi)
location<- c("xyz, sss, New Zealand", "USA", "Pris,France")
stri_trim(stri_match_first_regex(location, "(^|,)([^,]*?)$")[,3])
## [1] "New Zealand" "USA"         "France"
```

`stri_trim` removes unnecessary spaces before/after country name.